# Remove all entry with -1

Tags: c#

Say i have an integer array i1 with value {1,-1,-1,1};
is there an easy way to construct an array i2 with -1 removed, i.e. {1,1}
? Thanks.

Comment: `"1"` is a string, not an integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq will be your friend.

```
var i2 = i1.Where(m => m!= -1).ToArray()
```

Comment: heh, you need to be fast with your answers on SO :)

Comment: @YavgenyP and wake up before John Skeet ;)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus: Jon Skeet never sleeps

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LINQ, i guess this will work:

```
 int[] a = new int[] { 1, -1, 1 };
 int[] b = a.Where(t => t == 1).ToArray();
```

Of course, writing the loop or two yourself shouldnt be too complicated either.

Comment: it will come down to loops eventually, just that they are implemented for you, when you are using linq :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newArray = i1.Where(m => m!= -1).ToArray()
```