# Use of unassigned local variable error C#

Tags: c#

This is with regard to previous question posted a while ago
 [Remove -1 entry from integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833433/remove-all-entry-with-1)

I know there are blazing fast solutions , one line answers as posted in answer section  to previous posted question , but being a newbie I tried doing by for loops.

```
  int[] arr = new int[]{ 1, -1, -1, 1 };
            int[] new_arr;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
                if (arr[i] == -1)
                    continue;
                else
                    new_arr[index++] = arr[i];
            }
```

I am getting error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'new_arr'

what am I doing wrong.

**EDIT**

```
        int[] arr = new int[]{ 1, -1, -1, 1 };
        int[] new_arr = new[arr.Length]; //Error being shown at this line
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {

            if (arr[i] == -1)
                continue;
            else
                new_arr[index++] = arr[i];
        }

        for(int j=0;j<new_arr.Length;j++)
            Console.WriteLine(new_arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialized your array `new_arry`. You need to specify its size.

```
int[] new_arr = new int[10];
```

Inside your code you are doing:

```
new_arr[index++] = arr[i];
```

Here since the array has not been initialized and you are trying to use it, that is why you are getting this error.

**You may use `List<int>` instead of the array**, because it seems you are not sure about the Size of the array in your code.

So your code would be:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{ 1, -1, -1, 1 };
List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
int[] new_arr;
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
      {
       // Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
         if (arr[i] == -1)
              continue;
         else
            tempList.Add(arr[i]);
      }
new_arr = tmepList.ToArray();
```

Or the complete code can be shorten to:

```
int new_arr = arr.Where(r=> r!= -1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is warning that you haven't initialized the `new_arr` variable and you cannot use it later:

```
int[] new_arr = new int[arr.Length];
```

In this case I am initializing the `new_arr` array to the same size as the `arr` array.

Comment: Then you must have some other code that you are not showing here, because if you only make the change as I suggested it will compile.

Comment: Sir I have pasted the complete code in EDIT aboove indicating line in which error is shown to occur . Please help. Also is there no way to use array if size is not known beforehand ?

Answer (score 1):

you haven't assigned your variable new_arr. Therefore it is showing error. Your code can be like this-

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, -1, -1, 1 };
        int[] new_arr = new int[4];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            if (arr[i] == -1)
                continue;
            else
                new_arr[index++] = arr[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < new_arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new_arr[i]);

        }
```

You can't use any un-assigned or dangling variable in c#. Do not assign new_arr to null. It will throw null reference exception.

Comment: You can use ArrayList for having dynamic length. It provides same functionality as array i this context